# Split file line by line into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I want to have an array based on the lines in the file, but at the moment its a fixed sized array:

```
string[] converList = new string[6]; // Array containing TXT lines
```

Reading the file:

```
void ReadConver()
    {
        string line;
        int i = 0;

        System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Kennyist\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\soft140as3\\convert.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            converList[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a list then use ToArray to make it into an array:

```
var cList = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Kennyist\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\soft140as3\\convert.txt").ToList();
string[] converlist = clist.ToArray();
```

Also, use `(@'C:\Kennyist...')` instead of the double backslashes

Comment: Well that was overly simple, Found something like that on google but I got an error with it before. Thanks!

Comment: The result of `ReadAllLines` already is an array.  No need to use the LINQ `ToArray` extension method on it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing things the hard way, you can just use:

```
var arrTextLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Kennyist\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\soft140as3\convert.txt");
```

`arrTextLines` will be an object with the type `string[]`.

Answer (score -1):

Edited answer:

```
  string[] converList;
  System.IO.StreamReader file =
  new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Kennyist\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\soft140as3\\convert.txt");


  converList = new string[] { file.ReadToEnd() };
```

Thanks @Cole

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question at all? He wants to read a file into an array. This just creates an empty array of `Length` 0.

Comment: You don't understand .NET, do you? `new T[]` creates an array of size 0.

Comment: @ColeJohnson oh, my wrong, I understand now, Sorry, i'm new to generics functions and I use List<T> and not array maybe it'll work if it will be `string[] converList;`

Comment: I will edit my answer @ColeJohnson I now get what array is :D thank you :)

Comment: If you just use `string[] converList;`, you just did the equivalent of `string[] converList = null`.

Comment: Yes, that will make an array.